# Change day of the month in a Date to first day (01)

Tags: r, date, datetime

I want to set the day of month in a `Date` to start date of current month (`01`).
Now I use the following:

```
currentDate <- Sys.Date()  #for getting current system date eg:2012-11-06
formatDate <- format(currentDate, "%Y-%m")  #it return 2012-11
startDate <- as.Date(paste(formatDate, "-01", sep = ""))
# 2012-11-01
```

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: If in Linux, you may use system("date",intern=T) to extract the date information as a string and then edit it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, there is a one-liner for that using function `cut`:

```
cut(Sys.Date(), "month")
[1] 2012-11-01
Levels: 2012-11-01
```

Answer (score 17):

Also one line using format function:

```
format(Sys.Date(),"01-%m-%Y")
[1] "01-06-2017"
```

Comment: This has the added benefit of keeping it in a date format as opposed to converting it to a factor via `cut`.

Comment: `class(format(Sys.Date(),"01-%m-%Y"))` results as `"character"`.  But `class(cut(Sys.Date(), "month"))` results in `"factor"`. So, bothe these approaches need to Date conversion apporach!

Answer (score 13):

`lubridate`'s `floor_date` keeps it a Date

```
library(lubridate)

floor_date(Sys.Date(), "month")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
as.Date(paste0(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y-%m"), "-01"))
```

Comment: It would be useful to elaborate more on this solution, explaining how or why this solves the question being asked, or why it is better/different from the method described in the question or other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Using `lubridate` (also work with `sec`, `min`, `hour`, `mon`, `year`  etc.)

```
library(lubridate)

dt <- Sys.Date()
day(dt) <- 01

dt
# [1] "2018-01-01"
```