# How to replace the days in a date object in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to replace the different days in a Date object in R with the same day for all the object.

Let's take an example.

```
date = structure(c(10961, 10990, 11018, 11046, 11060, 11088, 11116, 
11144, 11214, 11235, 11249, 11263, 11305, 11354, 11382, 11423, 
11452, 11480, 11494, 11508), class = "Date")

 [1] "2000-01-05" "2000-02-03" "2000-03-02" "2000-03-30" "2000-04-13" "2000-05-11" "2000-06-08"
 [8] "2000-07-06" "2000-09-14" "2000-10-05" "2000-10-19" "2000-11-02" "2000-12-14" "2001-02-01"
[15] "2001-03-01" "2001-04-11" "2001-05-10" "2001-06-07" "2001-06-21" "2001-07-05"
```

I would like to get:

```
 [1] "2000-01-05" "2000-02-05" "2000-03-05" "2000-03-05" "2000-04-05" "2000-05-05" "2000-06-05"
 [8] "2000-07-05" "2000-09-05" "2000-10-05" "2000-10-05" "2000-11-05" "2000-12-05" "2001-02-05"
[15] "2001-03-05" "2001-04-05" "2001-05-05" "2001-06-05" "2001-06-05" "2001-07-05"
```

What I do is:

```
sub("%d", "05", date, perl = TRUE)
```

However, it doesn't work. I think the mistake is in the `pattern` and I don't know how to grasp just the day.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: The simplest `lubridate::day(date) <- 5`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas thanks! I tried just day() but couldn't find the function

Comment: `day` is a function in package `lubridate`. You need the package installed in your system.

Comment: [Change day of the month in a Date to first day (01)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247993/change-day-of-the-month-in-a-date-to-first-day-01). All answers (except the `cut` one) can easily be modified to your case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Base R:

```
date <- as.Date(sub("\\d{2}$", "05", date))
```

Package `lubridate`:

```
lubridate::day(date) <- 5
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `floor_date()` in `lubridate` to round dates down to the first day of each month and plus 4.

```
lubridate::floor_date(date, "month") + 4

#  [1] "2000-01-05" "2000-02-05" "2000-03-05" "2000-03-05" "2000-04-05"
#  [6] "2000-05-05" "2000-06-05" "2000-07-05" "2000-09-05" "2000-10-05"
# [11] "2000-10-05" "2000-11-05" "2000-12-05" "2001-02-05" "2001-03-05"
# [16] "2001-04-05" "2001-05-05" "2001-06-05" "2001-06-05" "2001-07-05"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you convert the date into `POSIXlt` object, you can change it's individual component.

```
date <- as.POSIXlt(date)
date$mday <- 5
as.Date(date)

# [1] "2000-01-05" "2000-02-05" "2000-03-05" "2000-03-05" "2000-04-05"
# [6] "2000-05-05" "2000-06-05" "2000-07-05" "2000-09-05" "2000-10-05"
#[11] "2000-10-05" "2000-11-05" "2000-12-05" "2001-02-05" "2001-03-05"
#[16] "2001-04-05" "2001-05-05" "2001-06-05" "2001-06-05" "2001-07-05"
```